# Can't pass items within a for loop to print two items together

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I've written a script in `node` to scrape the `titles` and `urls` to the titles of different posts from the landing page of a webpage and then fetch the `profile name` of each user from it's inner page. The only thing I can't solve is print the two things `items` and `output` within the `for loop`.

***How can I pass `items` within the `for loop` in order for the script to print `items` and `output` at the same time?***

I've tried like:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';
const host = 'https://stackoverflow.com';

function getPosts() {
    request(url, function(error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let linkstorage = [];
            $('.summary .question-hyperlink').each(function() {
                var items = $(this).text();
                var links = host + $(this).attr("href");
                linkstorage.push(links);
            });

            for (const newlink of linkstorage) {
                request(newlink, function(error, response, html) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                        var output = $(".user-details a").eq(0).text();
                        console.log(output);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
getPosts();
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable declarations and assignment can be separated in JavaScript. You can **define** the items variable outside the scope of the for loop where it is **assigned**

```
// define it outside the jquery function scope
       let items;

      $('.summary .question-hyperlink').each(function(){
        items = $(this).text();
        ...
      });

      for (const newlink of linkstorage){
        request(newlink,function(error,response,html){
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
          var $ = cheerio.load(html);
          var output = $(".user-details a").eq(0).text();
          console.log(output);
          console.log(items); // It is visible in this scope
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: In that case the script will print an individual item (last item of the array) multiple times @jakemingolla.

Comment: @MITHU true, I was mostly using it as a placeholder for the teaching moment :) I didn't know what "print `items` and `output` at the same time" specified

Answer (score 0):

`request` is deprecated. Using promises makes tasks like this much easier than the classic callback-style async API. `fetch` is built in to Node 18+, so I'll use that:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping";
const host = "https://stackoverflow.com";

const get = async url => {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }

  return response.text();
};

const getPosts = async () => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(await get(url));
  const links = [...$(".s-post-summary .s-link")]
    .map(e => $(e).attr("href"));
  const result = [];

  for (const link of links) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(await get(host + link));
    result.push({
      link,
      details: $(".user-details a").eq(0).text(),
    });
  }

  return result;
};

getPosts().then(result => console.log(result));
```

Note that selectors have changed a bit since the question was originally posted.